# How can I make a batch file discover if a directory is actually a Junction?

Tags: windows, directory, batch-file, junction

I'm writing a Batch file (.bat) and I couldn't find a way to discover if a given directory I have the path to is a real directory or a Junction (created on Windows 7 by using `mklink /j`). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Deleted my answer because I realized it wouldn't work on directory junctions as dir descends down into the directory when given a directory as a parameter

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that might have been the issue. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lousy technique but `fsutil reparsepoint query` *path to file* will fail (`%ERRORLEVEL%` will be 1) if the file is not a junction and succeed (`%ERRORLEVEL%` will be 0) if it is one. The other problem with this is `fsutil` wants you to be an administrator. Additionally, not all reparse points are directory junctions.

Comment: +1 In batch script there's no such thing as lousy; if it does the job then it's good stuff!!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for, but unfortunately it seems to be returning errorlevel 1 for everything. I do a " `dir /A:L %Link%>nul 2>nul` " followed by a " `if errorlevel 1 GOTO :LinkJunctionExists "%Link%"` ", is this right?

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer. Having admin rights is not an issue, and being a reparse point is enough for me. Unfortunately I have tested this - and it does indeed return an error if it is not a junction - but it does not set the errorlevel as you described (it always stays at 0).

Comment: NEVERMIND, there was something wrong with my terminal. Thanks a lot, this worked!

Comment: @David: Not quite, as requiring administrative privileges is a fairly hefty requirement, actually.

Answer (score 13):

In a batch script you can use the following:

```
 SET Z=&& FOR %%A IN (linkfilename) DO SET Z=%%~aA
 IF "%Z:~8,1%" == "l" GOTO :IT_A_LINK
```

this is quicker than calling `DIR /AL`.

The `%%~aA` gets the attributes of the "linkfilename",
 a 9 char string like `d--------` (a directory),
 or `d-------l` a link to a directory,
or `--------l` a link to a file.

`%Z:~8,1%` then grabs just the reparse point attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I have this little gem which will list all Junctions and their targets in your current directory:

```
for /F "delims=;" %j in ('dir /al /b') do @for /F "delims=[] tokens=2" %t in ('dir /a ^| findstr /C:"%j"') do @echo %j :: %t
```

Example output:

```
Application Data :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming
Cookies :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
Local Settings :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Local
My Documents :: C:\Users\AB029076\Documents
NetHood :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
PrintHood :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
Recent :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
SendTo :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
Start Menu :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Templates :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
TestLink :: C:\Users\AB029076\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
```